# How do I open a new page after validating an html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a project for college to create an online fleet management system. I just created to login form and hard-coded the correct credentials (as told to do so). Now I want the login page to open my next page when the correct credentials are validated but I can't figure out how to do so... Code attached.

html login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fleet Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function authenticate()
        {
            var authorised;
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if(username == "Myuser" && password == "SA1@123")
            {
                authorised = true;
                window.location("main.html")
            }
            else
            {
                authorised = false;
                alert("Incorrect credentials, Please try again");
            }
            return authorised;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
            <form name="logInForm" onsubmit="return authenticate()">            
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input id="username" type="text" name="uName" required="required">
                    <span>Username</span>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="pWord" required="required">
                    <span>Password</span>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

html page I want to open after successful login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fleet Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #23242a;
}
.box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 380px;
    height: 420px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,#45f3ff,#45f3ff);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
}
.box::after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 380px;
    height: 420px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,#45f3ff,#45f3ff);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.container
{
    position: absolute;
    inset: 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #28292d;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container h2
{
    color: #45f3ff;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.inputBox
{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.inputBox input
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #23242a;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    z-index: 10;
}
.inputBox span
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    pointer-events: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.inputBox input:valid ~ span,
.inputBox input:focus ~ span
{
    color: #45f3ff;
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(-34px);
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
.inputBox i
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: #45f3ff;  
 border-radius: 4px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 pointer-events: none; 
 z-index: 9;
}
.inputBox input:valid ~ i,
.inputBox input:focus ~ i
{
   height: 44px; 
}
input[type="submit"]
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #45f3ff;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="submit"]:active
{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

I've tried many things I've seen on the web (too many to type). I just could'nt find one that works with my specific code. I'm still a beginner so bear with me please!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location location.assign("main.html");

Comment: You can't do both, submit the form and redirect in the submit handler. Remove the redirection from the script, and set [action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action) attribute for the form. Note, that everyone visiting on your page can see the username and the password, this is just for an exercise only, right?

Comment: @Teemu yes you can as long as you preventDefault and maybe that's something that was worth saying also in my comment above

Comment: @DiegoD No, you can't, because `preventDefault` prevents the form submission.

Comment: @Teemu it should prevent the default event fulfillment by the browser that will send the GET/POST request to the action url. If you preventDefault in your onsubmit handler it should stop there. Just triggers the event, perform the comparison and that's all..just one moment before redirecting the browser navigation to the next url. That's what I meant saying that still you can. Not the best strategy but yet valid

Comment: @DiegoD Right, and only a single task will be fulfilled, not both.

Comment: @Teemu. ok I got it wrong when you said the first time.. yes of course you can't have both. I had to read more carefully

Comment: @Teemu yes this is just an exercise

Comment: @Teemu thank you, it worked! I just removed redirection and used action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default function by using: `<form name="logInForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return authenticate()">`

Secondly, use `window.location.replace("")` instead.

the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fleet Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function authenticate()
        {
            var authorised;
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            if(username == "Myuser" && password == "SA1@123")
            {
                authorised = true;
                window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
            }
            else
            {
                authorised = false;
                alert("Incorrect credentials, Please try again");
            }
            return authorised;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
            <form name="logInForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return authenticate()">            
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input id="username" type="text" name="uName" required="required">
                    <span>Username</span>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="pWord" required="required">
                    <span>Password</span>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```